# Find the Bayes estimate of $θ$

Tags: statistics

Can someone help me solve this out, please? Thanks a lot.

Find the Bayes estimate of $\theta$ based on a single observation of $5$ from a distribution that is uniform on the interval 0 to $\theta$. Use square-error loss and a prior distribution of $\theta$ which has p.d.f. $p(\theta) = \theta \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-\theta}$ where  $0<\theta <\infty$.

Comment: What have you tried? Here is a hint: what is the probability $P(5|\theta)$ since you know that the probability of an observation is uniform between $0$ and $\theta$? Once you know this, then you can write down $P(\theta | 5)$ using Bayes' rule and find where it has a peak.

Comment: p(θ|5)=e^(-θ)? Sorry i just start learnig Bayes and i am really confused with it..

Comment: That's almost correct, but what would happen if $\theta$ was smaller than 5? Could you ever draw a 5 from such a uniform distribution? Also, instead of just looking for the "peak" as I wrote, it sounds like you need the mean squared error. First work on getting to the point where you are confidence that you understand $p(\theta|5)$ then we can use the definition of mean squared error to finish off the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prior density is $p(\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta}$ for $\theta>0$, and the likelihood function is
$$
L(\theta) = \begin{cases} \frac 1 \theta & \text{for }\theta\ge5, \\  \\  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
Multiplying them, you get
$$
g(\theta)=p(\theta) L(\theta) = \begin{cases} e^{-\theta} & \text{for }\theta\ge5, \\  \\  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
Then we have
$$
\int_5^\infty g(\theta)\;d\theta = e^{-5},\text{ so }\int_5^\infty e^5 g(\theta)\;d\theta = 1.
$$
Therefore
$$f(\theta)= \begin{cases} e^{5-\theta} & \text{if }\theta>5 \\  \\  \\
0 & \text{if }\theta<5 \end{cases}$$
is the posterior probability density function.  With squared-error loss, the Bayes estimate is just the posterior expected value
$$
\int_5^\infty \theta f(\theta)\;d\theta = 6.
$$

Comment: Thank you evry much! I have a question:g(θ) =e^(-θ) (when θ greater than 5), e^(-θ) is a exponential distribution, why doesn't its mean just equal to 1? (why isn't 1 the final answer?)

Comment: Its mean is not $1$ because the values of random variables with this distribution are always in the interval $[5,\infty)$.  (And notice that it wouldn't make sense to use $1$ as an estimate of something that must obviously be at least $5$.  The observation must be between $0$ and $\theta$, and the observation was $5$, so $\theta\ge5$.)